# How to filter data and then select next 10 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am currently filtering my dataset based on certain statements as such :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

# filter dataset
data1[(data1['sepal length (cm)'] > 4) |  (data1['sepal width (cm)'] > 3)]
```

I want to be able to get the next 10 rows following each filter too and I am not sure how to even start that so for example when they find one row where the length is greater than 4, I want to return the next 10 as well as that one etc.

Please let me know how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

the dataset that you loaded has a sequential index starting at 0.

to get the 10 rows following a filter, you're looking for rows where the index is between `index of the most recent filtered row` and `10 + index of the most recent filtered row`

however, the filter that you have provided `(data1['sepal length (cm)'] > 4) |  (data1['sepal width (cm)'] > 3)` matches on every row. the minimum width is 2. so for this illustration i'll use the filter `sepal length (cm) == 4.6` and filter `the next 5 rows` instead of `10`.

```py
filt = data1['sepal length (cm)'] == 4.6
data1.loc[filt, 'sentinel'] = data1.index[filt]
data1.sentinel = data1.sentinel.ffill()
data1[(data1.index >= data1.sentinel) & (data1.index <= data1.sentinel + 5)]
```

This filters 21 rows below

```
    sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  target  sentinel
3                 4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2     0.0       3.0
4                 5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2     0.0       3.0
5                 5.4               3.9                1.7               0.4     0.0       3.0
6                 4.6               3.4                1.4               0.3     0.0       6.0
7                 5.0               3.4                1.5               0.2     0.0       6.0
8                 4.4               2.9                1.4               0.2     0.0       6.0
9                 4.9               3.1                1.5               0.1     0.0       6.0
10                5.4               3.7                1.5               0.2     0.0       6.0
11                4.8               3.4                1.6               0.2     0.0       6.0
22                4.6               3.6                1.0               0.2     0.0      22.0
23                5.1               3.3                1.7               0.5     0.0      22.0
24                4.8               3.4                1.9               0.2     0.0      22.0
25                5.0               3.0                1.6               0.2     0.0      22.0
26                5.0               3.4                1.6               0.4     0.0      22.0
27                5.2               3.5                1.5               0.2     0.0      22.0
47                4.6               3.2                1.4               0.2     0.0      47.0
48                5.3               3.7                1.5               0.2     0.0      47.0
49                5.0               3.3                1.4               0.2     0.0      47.0
50                7.0               3.2                4.7               1.4     1.0      47.0
51                6.4               3.2                4.5               1.5     1.0      47.0
52                6.9               3.1                4.9               1.5     1.0      47.0
```